# unidentified red dots (json) in chrome network panel response tab

Tags: php, json, angularjs, google-chrome, slim

I am developing an API using slim framework, when I test this api with postman, phostorms built in tool it works fine and returns valid json. But when I call it from angular it is not getting parsed by angular. It shows unexpected index error.

I tried monitoring the payload in the network tab, surprisingly there are some red bullet mark like dots are appended before the actual json response.

[image: screenshot in response tab]

but it is not showing up in the preview tab..

[image: screenshot in preview tab]

I don't have a clue where are those dots are coming. I googled about it and find a way about the BOM Problem on windows. But I am not sure how to solve it.
Can you please help me to understand the problem and rectify it. Is this a problem caused by code or database or something else.

For information I'm using

> - Operating System : Windows 7,
> - Browser : google chrome,
> - front end MVC : angular (problem only happens here),
> - Backend : Slim Framework (PHP),
> - Database : Mysql ( tables and columns have mixed collations       between utf8mb4_bin and latin1_swedish_ci)
> - IDE : PHPStorm 8

EDIT : screenshot from fiddler
I used fiddlr to see whats going on and here is the hexview of the response[image: hewview]

Comment: Running the request with Fiddler Tool running will allow you to see exactly what those red unprintable chars actually are

Comment: is backend API running on same domain and port as the page? Sounds like you have a CORS problem and the whitespace in response is irrelevant

Comment: yeah both are running in localhost now.

Comment: if I have CORS problem, I can see an error in chrome right? @charlietfl

Comment: normally would see not an error but a warning. Postman does not have same security restrictions for cross domain requests which is why it is working there. I am still assuming ports are different?

Comment: You do see a JSON response albeit mangled, ergo its not a CORS/SOP issue

Comment: I updated the question with the fiddler hex view, if that helps.

Comment: So the server is returning a load of nulls before the JSON, you would need to debug however you output the JSON from PHP

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/1yfnto/what_is_this_red_bulletdot_in_my_json_response_in/

Comment: I moved my code out of slim and tested it still getting the same problem.. I don't have a clue still.. can anyone tell me what can I do?

Comment: Can you add your PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a workaround to get rid of it but it shouldn't be really used in production. As I am in tight schedule to work on the front end I just use this as a fix.

I used output buffering ob_start() at the start and cleaned the buffer just before I echo json ob_clean() this removes all the characters from the response. But still can't figure out what is the cause. I am waiting for responses from someone who had the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
ob_start();
try(){
    //
}catch(){
   //
}finally(){
  ob_end_clean();
}
```

Comment: Use finally block with ob_end_clean() function to clean BOM characters